# Custom layouts in panels not allowing me to add content

Tags: 7, drush, panels, caching

I created custom layouts for panels in my theme/layouts folder which I linked up in my .info file.

When I create a new one I am able to select it as a layout in panels, but when I click the content tab the sections aren't there.  I've cleared the cache via admin and via drush at least a thousand times.  Last time this happened to me I downloaded the latest version of Panels and it seemed to fix the issue, except I added another layout after that and I'm getting the same issue.

As an example, this is what my content tab looks like for my variant.  http://cl.ly/image/343N0V133R24.  Any ideas why this is happening?  It seems like panels is caching for some reason, but I can't find a way to make it stop.

Comment: It might be a ctools/JavaScript issue. Views used to have a bug where something wouldn't load which turned out to be a ctools issue. Check the JavaScript console to see if you're getting error on the page, or maybe try using the jquery_update module to get the latest jQuery. Since it's custom you might check to see if the ajax server requests for the html to load are returning good data.

Comment: No error in the console.